# passing value from javascript to sql via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some problem when I pass variable across php , javascript and ajax.

html - when I change the selected value, ajax will post the new value:

```
<select name="PACKAGE_CATEGORY" id="PACKAGE_CATEGORY" onclick="fireAjax()" class="form-control" >
    <option value="0" disabled selected  hidden> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="PLINE">Phone Line Only</option>
    <option value="UNIFI">Unifi for New Registration</option>
    <option value="STREAMYX">Streamyx for New Registration</option>
    <option value="WEBE">Webe</option>
    <option value="DOME">Lease Line (DOME)</option>
</select>
```

ajax - I get the value by javascript and save it in var1:

```
<script>
function fireAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {var1: document.getElementById('PACKAGE_ID').innerHTML },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
}
```

javascript function - I want to take the value `var1` from ajax, but fail:

```
<script>
$(function () {
var pricestore = [
    <?php
    $var1 = $_POST['var1']; // I cannot get the var1, please help me T.T
    $sqlpid=mysqli_query($conn, "select no from product where P_NAME = '$var1' ");

    //some function
    //.............
    ?>
];
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have no element in the HTML you've shown with an `id` of `PACKAGE_ID`. Assuming you're trying to get the selected option of `PACKAGE_CATEGORY`, use `.value` instead of `. innerHTML`

Comment: I have changed from `. innerHTML` to `.value`, but it still can't get the value.May I know is it all my code wrong at the first of the time?

Comment: Did you also change the `id` as I suggested? Your current code is not retrieving the correct element

Comment: ya... But still get nothing

Comment: Then have you checked the console for errors? Have you ensured in the console that the value is being sent in the request? You're really not making this easy to help you.

Comment: I have change the id to `PACKAGE_CATEGORY`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158295/discussion-between-ng-miow-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: before you put your code anywhere production near take a look at [sql-injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: @yellowsir , may I know is it my code can be injected by sql? I not so sure about that, but is it dropdown list also can be injected?

Comment: @NGMiow , people can still chance the value from dropdown in html or build their own post request, and buildsomething like: `where P_NAME = '$var1' or 1=1` (or worse if you use * anywhere you could build a subselect on e.g. the user table and get email adresses, pwhashes and much more..) you could use mysqli/pdo [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1761588)

Answer (score 0):

Change **onclick()** to **onchange()**

```
<select name="PACKAGE_CATEGORY" id="PACKAGE_CATEGORY" onchange="fireAjax()" class="form-control" > //Here
<option value="0" disabled selected  hidden> -- select an option -- </option>
<option value="PLINE">Phone Line Only</option>
<option value="UNIFI">Unifi for New Registration</option>
<option value="STREAMYX">Streamyx for New Registration</option>
<option value="WEBE">Webe</option>
<option value="DOME">Lease Line (DOME)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Html:

```
  <select name="PACKAGE_CATEGORY" id="PACKAGE_CATEGORY" onchange="fireAjax()" class="form-control" >
    <option value="0" disabled selected  hidden> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="PLINE">Phone Line Only</option>
    <option value="UNIFI">Unifi for New Registration</option>
    <option value="STREAMYX">Streamyx for New Registration</option>
    <option value="WEBE">Webe</option>
    <option value="DOME">Lease Line (DOME)</option>
</select>
```

Javscript:

```
<script>
    function fireAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'form.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {var1: document.getElementById('PACKAGE_CATEGORY').value},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success");
            }
        });
    }
```

Changed onclick to onchange, changed id, changed innerHtml to value

Comment: I still can't get the value with this answer, but I think it's near

Comment: Is there any errors in console? try exiting form.php with print_r($_POST) ONLY

Comment: nope, nothing errors show.
I have try to use alert to show the `var1` , it show nothing too

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your ajax call into change event of selector,

```
$('#PACKAGE_CATEGORY').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'var1': $(this).val() 
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Still can't get the value. Is it change to change event is better than mine way?

Comment: I dunno the different, so just asking, not saying that this is not good

Comment: two ways are same i just remove function, any way did you add URL ?

Comment: please add console.log and check inside this $('#PACKAGE_CATEGORY').change(function(){